# What's name of state $|010\rangle+|101\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-state

I want to get some information about, the state below:

$$a|010\rangle+b|101\rangle,$$

in which $$a^2 + b^2 =1.$$

I want to know its name. Is there any article or information about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Bell states, we have the *even parity* states $|00\rangle \pm |11\rangle$ and the *odd parity* states $|01\rangle \pm |10\rangle$.

These are more generally [GHZ states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenberger%E2%80%93Horne%E2%80%93Zeilinger_state), which what you wrote is a 3-qubit GHZ state. Following the Bell-state convention, I would imagine the most appropriate descriptor for $|101\rangle \pm |010\rangle$ to be *an odd parity GHZ state*. But it's not a state with any significant importance so it's not generally given a name.

Answer (score 3):

There's not a common name for this specific state.

It's a GHZ state $|000\rangle + |111\rangle$ with the middle qubit flipped.

Comment: This answer is true for some $a$ and $b$.

Comment: The question in the title asks about |000> + |111> (where a=b=1).